# Batch 'FOR' Loop Parser

Tags: batch-file

I have a small block of code that is supposed to parse through a file called data.dta but for some reason it keeps saying ( unexpected at this time, here is the code(I put a comment by the line that gives me an error):

```
:load
cd %appdata%\.Trek
FOR /f "eol=#" %%t IN (Resources\Data\data.dta) DO ( ::problem line
        set count=1
    set cor=0
    FOR /f "tokens=1-2 delims=^=" %%f IN ("%%t") DO (
        If %count% == 1 (
            IF %%f==VERSION set cor=1
        )
        If %count% == 2 (
            IF %cor%==1 (
                set cor=0
                set ver=%%f
            )
        )
        set /a count=%count%+1
    )
)    
Title TREK Unmounted Console Version: %ver%
```

Contents of data.dta:

```
VERSION=ALPHA 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can spot one major problem, you need to enable delayed expansion for it to work.

In a code block, all variables will have the value of what they were set ***before*** the code block started. If you set a variable ***inside*** a code block, it will only have that value once it is ***outside*** of the code block.

Try this example:

```
@echo off
set var=1
echo %var%
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    set /a var+=1
    echo %var%
)
echo %var%
pause>nul
```

The output will be:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
6
```

Now, try it with delayed expansions enabled, and replace the percent signs with exclamation marks:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var=1
echo %var%
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    set /a var+=1
    echo !var!
)
echo %var%
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
6
```

So, change your code to:

```
:load
cd %appdata%\.Trek
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "eol=#" %%t IN (Resources\Data\data.dta) DO ( 
    set count=1
    set cor=0
    FOR /f "tokens=1-2 delims=^=" %%f IN ("%%t") DO (
        If !count! == 1 (
            IF %%f==VERSION set cor=1
        )
        If !count! == 2 (
            IF !cor!==1 (
            set cor=0
            set ver=%%f
            )
        )
        set /a count+=1
    )
)    
Title TREK Unmounted Console Version: %ver%
endlocal
```

...And see what happens now.